# COPY and ADD not working in Dockerfile

Tags: tomcat, docker, bitnami

We have a dockerfile as

```
FROM bitnami/tomcat

EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8009

ADD values.war /opt/bitnami/tomcat/data/
```

Except the values.war file never seems to be added, when we

```
docker exec -it values /bin/bash
```

And check the `/opt/bitnami/tomcat/data/` directory the war file is not copied.

However we tried the following and when we connected into the docker container the file was copied

```
FROM bitnami/tomcat

EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8009

RUN mkdir -p /var/app
ADD values.war /var/app
```

So that led us to think that the issue was with the directory and therefore we tried the following

```
FROM bitnami/tomcat

EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8009

RUN ls -l /opt/bitnami/tomcat/data/
```

which gave the output

```
ls: cannot access /opt/bitnami/tomcat/data/: No such file or directory
```

when building the image

We think the issue is because the `FROM` image `bitnami/tomcat` uses that directory as a volume or such. This is probably the code to the original bitnami/tomcat image, though we are not sure.

https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-tomcat/blob/master/9.0/Dockerfile

Any ideas on how to add the file to the tomcat directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the downsides of defining a volume inside the Dockerfile and the reason why [I don't recommend defining them there](https://boxboat.com/2017/01/23/volumes-and-dockerfiles-dont-mix/). The behavior of docker is undefined when you attempt to modify files in a volume during a build, it may depend on your version of docker or other external variables, so for portability the best thing is to not do it.

Since you're working with an image from another party, I'd raise an issue with them to get the line removed (feel free to point them to my blog post for the explanation). And until that happens, you can checkout [their build files from github](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-tomcat/tree/master/9.0) and change the Dockerfile to build your own version of your base image.

For reference, here's one of the notes about [defining a volume in the Dockerfile from docker's docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume) (say that 3 times fast):

> **Changing the volume from within the Dockerfile:** If any build steps
>   change the data within the volume after it has been declared, those
>   changes will be discarded.

Comment: Alright, it is along the lines of what we thought though we did not know the specifics, additionally do you know if there if there is any possibility of any work around for this without forking and changing the build files (though it seems unlikely)?

Comment: No workaround that I know other than to manage the directory as a volume directly instead of trying to change the files in the build scripts.

Answer (score 4):

Sameer from Bitnami here.

The issue indeed is with the VOLUME's defined in the `Dockerfile`. We recognise this as a flaw in our Dockerfile and we are working towards fixing this issue in all our Dockerfiles.

Answer (score 2):

Just want to inform you that the Bitnami Docker images no longer declare `VOLUME` in the Dockerfile making it easier for our users to extend and customize the docker images. Hope you find this change helpful.

If you have any further questions, please join our stack community at http://slack.oss.bitnami.com/.